# Finding a permutation $ \alpha $ given $ \alpha^4 $

Tags: group-theory, permutations, cyclic-groups

I have the following question:

Find a permutation $\alpha ∈ S_7 $ such that $\alpha^4 = (2 1 4 3 5 6 7)$. Is $\alpha$ unique?

How should I go about this? I've tried a few different trial and error type solutions but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe find $\beta$ first with $\beta^2 = (2143567)$ and then do the same for $\beta$?

Comment: Can you find the order of $\alpha$ in $S_7$? How does that help?

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/329593/4280, it seems