# If $\beta\in S_7$ and $\beta^4=(2,1,4,3,5,6,7)$ then find $\beta$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

If $\beta\in S_7$ and $\beta^4=(2,1,4,3,5,6,7)$ then find $\beta$.

I cant seem to find a value for $\beta$ . It is given $\beta^4=(2,1,4,3,5,6,7)$. I dont have a clue about the process of evaluating $\beta$.

Is there any general way to solve these sort of problems? I am not quite getting it . . . There may be some posts relating to these topic on this site but I can't seem to find it either . . .

Comment: Here's one! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329593/finding-a-permutation-and-number-of-from-powers-of-the-permutation

Comment: $(\beta^4)^2=\beta^8=\beta^7\beta=\beta$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner how did u know that $o(\beta)=7$? Doesn't $S_7$ has $7!$ elements?...

Comment: $\beta$ is a $7$-cycle